# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I am getting the following error whenever I want to create a table in MySQL.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( 32 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , `visitor_day` SMALLINT( 2 ) NOT NUL' at line 7
```

code:

```
CREATE TABLE `visitors_table` (
`ID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`visitor_ip` VARCHAR( 32 ) NULL ,
`visitor_browser` VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL ,
`visitor_hour` SMALLINT( 2 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00',
`visitor_minute` SMALLINT( 2 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00',
`visitor_date` TIMESTAMP( 32 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
`visitor_day` SMALLINT( 2 ) NOT NULL ,
`visitor_month` SMALLINT( 2 ) NOT NULL ,
`visitor_year` SMALLINT( 4 ) NOT NULL ,
`visitor_refferer` VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL ,
`visitor_page` VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL
) TYPE = MYISAM ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of errors fixed here:

```
CREATE TABLE `visitors_table` (
`ID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`visitor_ip` VARCHAR( 32 ) NULL ,
`visitor_browser` VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL ,
`visitor_hour` SMALLINT( 2 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00',
`visitor_minute` SMALLINT( 2 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00',
`visitor_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`visitor_day` SMALLINT( 2 ) NOT NULL ,
`visitor_month` SMALLINT( 2 ) NOT NULL ,
`visitor_year` SMALLINT( 4 ) NOT NULL ,
`visitor_refferer` VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL ,
`visitor_page` VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed it, I'll mark this as answer in about 9 minutes. Sorry for the other 2, only can select one

Comment: I had "corrected" your NULL's to NOT NULL at the end there. I've put them back, but wanted to make sure you have the version you want.

Answer (score 3):

`TIMESTAMP` does not support precision. Not until MySQL **5.6**, that is, where sub-second resolution is possible.

Remove the `( 32 )` from the `TIMESTAMP` definition.

Comment: I deleted ( 32 ) now I get `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE = MYISAM' at line 13`

Joshua Martell gave the fix tho..

Answer (score 3):

`TIMESTAMP` does not have a size and you should use `engine` instead of `type`

```
CREATE TABLE `visitors_table` (
`ID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`visitor_ip` VARCHAR( 32 ) NULL ,
`visitor_browser` VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL ,
`visitor_hour` SMALLINT( 2 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00',
`visitor_minute` SMALLINT( 2 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00',
`visitor_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
`visitor_day` SMALLINT( 2 ) NOT NULL ,
`visitor_month` SMALLINT( 2 ) NOT NULL ,
`visitor_year` SMALLINT( 4 ) NOT NULL ,
`visitor_refferer` VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL ,
`visitor_page` VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL
) engine = MYISAM ;
```

Comment: Thank you, I have to mark Joshua Martell as answered because I used his code first and it worked. Sorry but thank you